# Autheticating users from a third party application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

I've got a java web-app in which I need users to create documents. These documents must be allocated in a SP 2013 server. My first idea was to use users' themselves SP sites to allocate their documents. Nowadays, I would be happy saving their documents in a shared SP site with my own user.
I've been trying to connect to the SP REST services from a browser with no problem. But, I could not connect from my application though I have been using the same user what I used on the browser.

I have been having a look at the MS documentation, forums, etc. All what I have been able to find was C# related.

Could anyone authenticate against SP2013 from java or javascript/jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery /JavaScript based authentication might not work as you will face the issue of cross origin error due to different domains.

you can write a C# based application which allows you to authenticate to SharePoint and upload data to respective library.

In Java, there is a good thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570383/basic-authentication-from-java-to-sharepoint-2013-rest-api